# IIS website "failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\inetpub\vhosts\" but file exists there

Tags: php, windows, apache, iis

Hi I have been struggle with a wierd problem. I am using IIS and moved one of my web site folder to desktop of my server and then put it back now I see

> Warning: include_once(./lib/config.inc.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\inetpub\vhosts\politikacim.net\httpdocs\index.php on line 12
>
> Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening './lib/config.inc.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;./includes;./pear') in C:\inetpub\vhosts\politikacim.net\httpdocs\index.php on line 12

this kind of error. I looked at my root folder and see it's permission is system and administrator full access , how can I make it work ? Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

Given the error messages, you'd need to have your `config.inc.php` file in one of the following locations:

```
C:\inetpub\vhosts\politikacim.net\httpdocs\lib\config.inc.php
C:\inetpub\vhosts\politikacim.net\httpdocs\includes\config.inc.php
C:\inetpub\vhosts\politikacim.net\httpdocs\pear\config.inc.php
```

system/admin permissions are irrelevant if your webserver is running under some other user account. You must grant permissions based on your webserver's userid, not your own personal one, or some other account.

Comment: You are right, thank you very much. I added IIS_User and Plesk_user and their permission. And now it's working thank you very much again.

Comment: Sorry my friend I need to ask you another question about this. I have changed permission and I can now include config and other files but this time I got "This webpage has a redirect loop" error. This pages were working before I copied that folder to my desktop and put it back to vhost

Comment: that'd be an IIS configuration issue, or something in the code in the pages causing it.

Comment: Thanks. I'll search for it.But I guess it is still about permissions :S