# PHP Include not working into my coding

Tags: php, include

I am running a website locally.

I have one main folder, which contains all main coding for normal users, it is a file named `main.php`.

Inside this main folder I have another folder for the admin, which contains, for example, the file named `announcement2.php`. However, when I try to include it in the front page (`index.php`), an error appears, it is like the server cannot read the file inside the admin folder.

The error is:

```
Warning: include(../admin/announcement2.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\pods\main.php on line 85

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '../admin/announcement2.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\pods\main.php on line 85
```

And here is the code to include the file in the admin folder from `main.php`

```
<td><?php include '../admin/announcement2.php'; ?></td>
```

Comment: `include 'admin/announcement2.php'`

Comment: post your directories structure

Comment: change post title - the problem is not that the pages are user and admin, the problem is with php includes

Comment: What does `echo getcwd()` write?

Comment: are you able to open http://localhost/admin/announcement2.php?? or maybe it is http://localhost/pods/admin/announcement2.php

Comment: hi kinjal, I'm able to open `localhost/pods/admin/announcement2.php`, but the other one, It's cannot be open.

Comment: hi nice, I've try `<td><?php echo getcwd() ?></td>`, and It's appear `C:\xampp\htdocs\pods`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably just means either (a) permissions are incorrect (web server can't read the file), or more likely, (b) the path is incorrect. If you `echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];` you'll see the path of the script, which would shed light on what path to actually use. But it's usually faster to try a few variations ...

```
include '../admin/announcement2.php';
include 'admin/announcement2.php';
include '../../admin/announcement2.php';
```

... until something works.

Comment: thanks for your concern, I've paste your short path coding into my coding, but It's still not solve the problem.

Comment: In the PHP file with the `<td></td>` element, replace the `include` with `echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];` and tell me what you see

Comment: hi @neokio, I do like this <td><?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?></td> and It's appear like this /pods/main.php

Comment: hey neokio, how to make a highlight like you do above, that have grey background.. It's easy to answer when people ask,

Comment: you wrap what you want highlighted with the tilde character ... (next to the number 1 on my keyboard). so what you know know is that the include needs to be relative to that `/pods/` directory. what is the complete path to the announcement2.php file? is it `/pods/admin/announcement2.php`? or is `/admin` at the same level as `/pods`?

Comment: @neokio: it is a backtick (`), not a tilde (~). It's next to the 1 only on English keyboards.

Comment: ok the complete path to get announcement2 is `C:\xampp\htdocs\pods\admin\announcement2.php` and `/admin` are located inside `pods` folder.. thanks for your lesson about this highlight.. :-)

Comment: then you want `include('admin/announcement2.php');` ... try using the complete path `include('C:\xampp\htdocs\pods\admin\announcement2.php');` ... if that doesn't work, it's probably a permission issue.

Comment: also, follow @nico's suggestion ... what does `echo getcwd();` output?

Comment: something else worth mentioning, you've asked 5 questions but 'accepted' none. you are more likely to get good/fast answers on stackoverflow if you accept their answers (clicking the checkmark next to their answer) and upvote (clicking the up arrow). we programmers are quite vain :) many take it way too seriously. but really, reputation (peer review) is what makes stackoverflow work so well.

Comment: neokio, I've try your code `include('C:\xampp\htdocs\pods\admin\announcement2.php');` but still not working.. you said if It's not working, maybe it's related with my permission issue, but I have check my coding, there is no coding related to persmission inside announcement2.php and main.php

Comment: Hmm.. does this post help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8772974/iis-website-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory-in-c-inetpub-vhos

Comment: Actually, try this ... `var_dump(get_include_path());` ... This will show the include path, and tell us if you need to repair the include_path parameter in your php.ini file.

Comment: Another thing that can't hurt ... replace `include` with `include_once`.

Comment: And another ... `include_once dirname(__FILE__) .'\admin\announcement2.php';`

Comment: Nope, not the same ... Here are the wikis for [IIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP) and [XAMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services)

Comment: Did you try `include_once('admin\announcement2.php');` ?

Comment: neokio, I'll try it later and I'll feedback you back, thanks so much for your help.. you're good helper..

Comment: Hi `@neokio`, I have try all above, but still not working.. :'(

Comment: do you want to see my coding, how it work? here or by email personally?

Comment: That probably wouldn't be very useful. I'd suggest you try this:
1) Make a php file named "test1.php" with only this in it: `<?php include('test2.php'); ?>`
2) Make a php file named "test2.php" with only this in it: `<?php echo "Success!"; ?>`
3) Load test1.php in a browser (http://localhost/test1.php)
4) If that succeeds, create a directory "test3", and move test2.php into it. Change test1.php to `<php include('test3\test2.php'); ?> and see if that works.

Comment: You need to figure out what is working and what is not working. This is simple troubleshooting by elimination. You don't know what mistake you are making yet. So start with the basics. Let me know how that goes...

Comment: hi neokio, I've try your simple tutorial, from step 1 to 4 everything working as well..

Comment: hi neokio, thanks for your help, I've check my coding inside admin directory, and I found a bit mistake at database declaration. I've fixed it and now It's working as usual. thanks again for your help & patience.

Comment: good work! 90% of debugging is figuring out _where_ the bug is. it's important to check your assumptions at every step. good luck!